# When I try to hash the password, mongoose validation is not working for password filled

Tags: node.js, express, model-view-controller, mongoose-schema, bcrypt

With the help of bcrypt library, when I try to hash the password, the password validation is not working which is already defined in schema. Password filled is required however it is being submitted without password. If I replace `password: hashpassword` with `password:req.body.password` the validation starts working.

How can I implement this?

Controller:

```
import { User } from "../model/userModel.js";
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';



export const addUser = async (req, res) => {

    try {
        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt();
        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);

        const addNewUser = new User({

            username: req.body.username,
            email: req.body.email,
            password: hashedPassword
        })
        await addNewUser.save();
        return res.status(200).json({ "res": 'User has been registered successfully' });

    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({ "res": `${err} Error occurred while signing up the user` });
    };
};



import mongoose from "mongoose";
```

User schema :

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Username is required'],
        minlength: [2, 'Username required minimum 2 char'],
        maxlength: [20, 'username can not contain more than 20 char'],
        trim: true

    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Email is required'],
        unique: [true, 'Email is already registered in server'],
        trim: true

    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Password is required'],
        trim: true,
        minlength: [6, 'Password can not be less than 6 char'],

    }
});
```

Model:

```
export const User = mongoose.model('userspace', userSchema);
```

Comment: Where do you do the validation?  If you're saving it encrypted, then the validator needs to encrypt before comparing.

Comment: The issue happens when I perform POST Req, data should not be posted if the password filled is empty as I already have mentioned in Schema however form gets submitted even if the password filled is empty.

Answer (score 0):

`bcrypt.hash` never returns an empty string, even if you feed it an empty body.  You always get the salt.  If you want to forbid an empty password, you will need to do that validation yourself.

Comment: Yes, I know it doesn't return an empty string, even it converts the empty password filled in hashing values and store it in database. In the case of "password : req.body.password" it doesn't submitted if the password is empty and if it is "password : hashedpassword " form gets submitted with empty password from front end.

Comment: This is all server-side code, right?  "Submitting" is a client-side concept.  Nothing you do in the server will change the form behavior.  All you're changing is your RESPONSE to the form.

Answer (score 0):

** The issue has been solved. I just add a small block of code before hashing the password. It checks for empty password, if it is not empty then in else block it executes further statement **

```
try {

    const passwordValues = req.body.password;

    if (!passwordValues) {
        return res.status(400).json({ "res": "Password filled can not be empty" });

    } else if (passwordValues.length < 6) {
        return res.status(400).json({ "res": "Password can not be less than 6 char" });
    } else {

        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt();
        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);


        const addNewUser = new User({

            username: req.body.username,
            email: req.body.email,
            password: hashedPassword
        })
        await addNewUser.save();
        return res.status(200).json({ "res": 'User has been registered successfully' });
    }
} catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json({ "res": `${err} Error occurred while signing up the user` });
};
```

};

Comment: You might want to use a 4XX status code like [400](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400) when the password doesn't meet the requirements

Comment: My bad. Yes I should use the 400 status code instead of 500. Thank you for pointing it  out.